# Defibrillator from China

Tags: heart-disease, home-medical-equipment, safety, aed-defibrillator

I would like to have defibrillator in my summerhouse, but I found that it cost a lot (1000USD) and it is overpraised since it contains almost nothing inside. I decided to look for one in China online store, but found only demo equipment. Does anybody have experience in buying cheep defibrillator? Can I use demo defibrillator from Ali-express?

Comment: Demo defibrillators are for training and don't actually do anything.

Comment: @CareyGregory Willing to expand that into an answer? I think just a link to a demo defibrillator and the claim would suffice

Comment: I guess they not allowed to sell real medical equipment and they sell them like demo.